# Capture/Void/Refund not showed in magento admin area

Tags: payment, payment-gateway

I have a custom payment plugin that so far has only authorize functionality. 
This means that in my model I have only:

```
protected $_canAuthorize = true;
protected $_canCapture = false;
protected $_canRefund = false;
protected $_canVoid = false;
```

I can close the payment, but when I create the invoice I don't see any option for refund, void, capture. Is this related to the fact that all the others flags are set to false and that the functions are not implemented?

Comment: I don't know much about payment, but I think the others can help if you post at least the other flags, better the whole class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams straight forward to me. If the payment methods does not allow `caprure, refund and void` it seams normal not to have the options in the invoices.
But just to make sure, if you drill down in the code starting from `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::canVoid()` you will find this line:

```
$canVoid = $this->getOrder()->getPayment()->canVoid($this);
```

that will get you to `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment::canVoid(Varien_Object $document)` where you will find this line:

```
$this->_canVoidLookup = (bool)$this->getMethodInstance()->canVoid($document);
```

Going deeper you end up in `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::canVoid()` that simply returns `$this->_canVoid`.
I didn't check, but I have a feeling that it's the same for `capture` and `refund`.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. I'm working on `eBizCharge` payment gateway and unable to see the **void** button. `class Mage_Ebizcharge_Model_CCPaymentAction extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc` is my class declaration and I'd set the values `$_canCapture = true; $_canRefund = true; $_canVoid = true;`.