# Paypal Authorization is voided in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal

I am getting following error in magento admin panel :
**PayPal gateway has rejected request. Authorization is voided (#10600: Authorization voided).**
I have voided the transaction from paypal account and now want to cancel the order from magento but above error occurs.
The credit memo correlated to the voided Paypal transaction cannot be created since the invoice of the transaction is in cancelled status.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The administrator should manually create an Offline Credit Memo to correlate with the voided Paypal transaction.

Comment: Yes you are right even I was trying the same but the Credit Memo button is not visible. As the credit memo correlated to the voided Paypal transaction cannot be created since the invoice of the transaction is in cancelled status.

Comment: Please help as I am not able to go further.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::canVoid()
```

Refer to code:

```
$canVoid = $this->getOrder()->getPayment()->canVoid($this);
```

This may be a help to you.

Check this [LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7846/capture-void-refund-not-showed-in-magento-admin-area) for more explanation on void function.

Comment: I just want to cancel the order from admin panel of magento. How can this code help me cancelling the order?